# Why is where highlighted?

Tags: visual-c++, intellisense, keyword

In VS 2010 C++ when I type where it gets highlighted, why? It is not a keyword so what's the reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a C++/CLI keyword, for constraining generics: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hsutter/archive/2003/11/23/53519.aspx

The Visual C++ Editor has to do syntax highlighting for both standard C++ and C++/CLI, and there isn't a separate file extension for C++/CLI code.

Comment: I would say it's a limitation.  The editor has to do color-coding of files that are `#include`d into multiple projects with different settings, or when no project is open at all.